# How to fill a nullable integer column and convert it into a serial primary key in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

My table contains an integer column (`gid`) which is nullable:

```
 gid | value
-------------
  0  |   a
     |   b
  1  |   c
  2  |   d
     |   e
```

Now I would like to change the `gid` column into a `SERIAL` primary key column. That means filling up the empty slots with new integers. The existing integers must remain in place. So the result should look like:

```
 gid | value
-------------
  0  |   a
  3  |   b
  1  |   c
  2  |   d
  4  |   e
```

I just can't figure out the right SQL command for doing the transformation. Code sample would be appreciated...

Comment: If you want to completely revamp the table then you can use this : - http://hastebin.com/tetulodami.sql (_NOTE:this will create new `gid`s that starts with 1_,_So this is not a good idea if `gid` has any relation with other table_)

Comment: If you want *continuous* integers, you're using the wrong thing, because sequences can have gaps and holes.

Comment: @CraigRinger Err - actually I don't know. It should be a serial PK. So anything that is unique should do - I guess.

Comment: @n1000 OK, you're fine then. It's just worth being sure because if you're relying on no gaps, as some apps do, you'll be in trouble with `SERIAL`. Lots of people don't realise this, which is why I tend to bring it up when words like *continous* are used.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for bringing it up then! Will edit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `serial` is "just" a column that takes it default value from a sequence. 
Assuming your table is named `n1000` then the following will do what you want.

The first thing you need to do is to create that sequence:

```
create sequence n1000_gid_seq;
```

Then  you need to make that the "default" for the column:

```
alter table n1000 alter column gid set default nextval('n1000_gid_seq');
```

To truly create a "serial" you also need to tell the sequence that it is associated with the column:

```
alter sequence n1000_gid_seq owned by n1000.gid;
```

Then you need to advance the sequence so that the next value doesn't collide with the existing values:

```
select setval('n1000_gid_seq', (select max(gid) from n1000), true);
```

And finally you need to update the missing values in the table:

```
update n1000 
  set gid = nextval('n1000_gid_seq')
where gid is null;
```

Once this is done, you can define the column as the PK:

```
alter table n1000 
   add constraint pk_n1000
   primary key (gid);
```

And of course if you have turned off autocommit you need to `commit` all this.

Comment: Awesome - it worked! This would have taken me ages to figure out.

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that your generated sequence values will not have gaps, due to rolled back transactions, unclean shutdowns, etc. You can have a table contain `100, 120, 121, 122, 190, ...`. If you need to avoid gaps, then (a) try to redesign so you don't, and (b) search for "postgresql gapless sequence"